# Apache Camel - method shortcut to jump to aggregator when exception thrown in the middle of a multiple step split route

Tags: apache-camel

I'd like to ask if there is some way to skip rest of the split route and jump directly to aggregator part, when in the exception handler I mark the split route to continue.

I have a route like this:

- receive a message
- fetch config for 3 endpoints
- merge config and message as a tuple for each endpoint, and create a list of it
- `.split()`, and in the split route I convert message according to config for each endpoint(`s1`), fetch oauth token(`s2`), send to final endpoint with token(`s3`), collect response for each endpoint(`s4`), aggregate(split aggregator; splitting ends here, let's call it `sa`)
- return as a whole one result
- stop

You can see, in the split route there are 4 steps(s1-s4); if any of these step fails I want to jump to aggregation(`sa`). For example, it does not make sense to continue the split route, if s1 or s2 fails.

I define an `onException()` clause to handle the exception and mark it to continue(`continued(true)`),because anyway I want to reach aggregator. Also, if I mark `continue(false)`, not only split route, but the whole route(meaning the main route even before splitting) will be rolled back. I want to decide rollback after getting all the causes/exceptions in each split branch.

I have a workaround for a simple case, which is, in exception handler for errors in s2, I add a property in the exchange `oauth_failed` to be `true`, and add a condition check `choice().when()` after s2; if this prop is null, then go to `s3` (continue sending). Solely for this purpose I must isolated `s3` as a separate route(`direct:s3`).

```
.bean(S2Bean.class)
.choice()
    .when(simple("${exchangeProperty.oauth_failed} == null")) // null = continue the flow
        .to("direct:s3")
    .endChoice()
    // otherwise, it will skip s3 and s4, and jump to aggregator directly
.end()
```

But, what can I do if s1 throws exception? Do I need to isolate s2 as a direct endpoint too? Then each step in the pipeline should be a separate endpoint. I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution: use `doTry` and `doCatch` in split route and don't `.stop()`.

```java
from("direct:split")
    .doTry()
        .bean(S1Bean.class)
        .bean(S2Bean.class)
        .bean(S3Bean.class)
        .bean(S4Bean.class)
    .endDoTry()
    .doCatch(javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException.class) // oauth timeout
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Time out, never retry, just aggregate")
        .bean(MyGenericExceptionHandler.class)
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Other exceptions, mark as failed, aggregate")
        .bean(MyGenericExceptionHandler.class)
    .end();
```

And in the `MyGenericExceptionHandler`, `exchange.getIn().setBody(xxx)` to set body to the expected type which my aggregator needs. The exception is in `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)`, response code is null. (I create a dto to contain both status code and/or exception, so that either success or failure, I aggregate with same class)

Don't call `stop()`.